# Process monitor which takes 100% CPU usage after 5-6 hours

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have engineered a process monitor which works fine but after 5 or 6 hours it takes 100% CPU usage.on physical PC it works fine but on VM it takes 100% usage.plz tell me what is the problem.coding part has two threads one for deleting the closed process and one is for capture the new process.

```
private void getPorcess()
{
    int pid=0;
    int pid1=0;

    ArrayList oProList1 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList oProList2 = new ArrayList();


    while (true)
    {
        Process[] oPrcs = Process.GetProcesses();

       if (oPrcs.Length < oProList1.Count)
       {
           foreach (Process pr1 in oPrcs)
           {
               pid1 = pr1.Id;
               string p = pr1.ProcessName;

               oProList2.Add(pid1);

           }
           //MessageBox.Show(oProList2.Count.ToString());
           oProList1.Clear();
           oProList1.AddRange(oProList2);
           oProList2.Clear();
       }
       foreach (Process pr in oPrcs)
       {
               pid = pr.Id;
               if (!oProList1.Contains(pid))
               {
                   oProList1.Add(pid);
                   string szres = "";
                   try
                   {
                       string prcsname = pr.Modules[0].FileName;
                       if ("")
                       {


                       }

                   }
                   catch 
                   {

                   }
                }
        }
         Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
}
```

Comment: @dnl, nonsense.  Time to pull out the ouija board!

Comment: "my car doesn't run, plz tell me why" <-- @SunilRai86: can you give me the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> plz tell me what is the problem

A bug which causes it to use 100% of your CPU.

You should fix this bug to make it not use 100% of your CPU.

Comment: I think this is as relevent to answers as it is to questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/joke-questions-please-refrain/ (now comments, on the other hand...)